# Should I use more rosin if aerial silk training makes my finger joints hurt for days?

Tags: pain, joints

I've been getting into aerial silk, 2 trainings per week. I have never done much sports where one is required to hold up their body weight by their hands for extended periods of time (and sometimes just a single hand). I do around 7-10 hours of sports per week in general so I'm fit, progressing very quickly and probably increasing the load on my hands very fast for a beginner.

I have barely used any rosin because I read it makes you weak and is intended more for performance than training. But now after like 3 weeks, the joints in my fingers hurt (mostly one per non-thumb finger, but the others also a little).

It's easily bearable and the pain just about goes away before the next training. But, as a runner, if I had that much pain in my knees I would immediately stop training and get professional help if it kept coming back after training.

Should I use more rosin to reduce the training load on my hands to a better level? Should I train less, go down to once per week for a month?

Comment: The small muscles and tendons in the fingers need time to adapt to a new workload. It's similar in climbing: the larger, more-used muscles and joins adapt more quickly than the fingers. Even mild inflammation in joints can have a disproportionate effect. I'd be a little surprised if more rosin helped more than a wee bit. Instead focus on finger joint care; this could include icing to reduce inflammation after training, anti-inflammatory foods, and a rest period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IME, yes, rosin lowered the required gripping force *dramatically*.  Which meant I was putting less force on my finger joints, which meant they didn't get hurt as much or as often.  TBF, I wasn't going pro, only did a handful of performances,...

I'm not sure I agree with "save rosin for performances", I'm big on "nothing new on race day".  But even if you do want to practice without rosin, you can start out *with* rosin, then **taper** off once you're doing a few practices a week without much of any pain.

I also would temporarily back off from practice, a little bit past when it stops hurting.  But I was definitely the most cautious one in my group (didn't progress as fast, but no injuries), so take that for what it's worth.

Good luck with whatever you end up doing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the meantime my hands mostly stopped hurting. Kept the training at a similar average of 2/week, but sometimes 1 and sometimes 3. I use as much rosin-in-a-sock as possible but didn't get any of the higher strength types. I think training load on the hands probably decreased with better technique and larger repertoire of known moves where I don't spend much time hanging around cluelessly.